# Multiple query in Android Contact

Tags: android, android-contacts

Trying to get NAME and NUMBER using android contact picker

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '"
                + ("1") + "'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
```

but unfortunately I am getting:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: has_phone_number: , while compiling: SELECT _id, display_name, data1 FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1 AND mimetype = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2') AND (has_phone_number = '1') ORDER BY display_name COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC
```